# get x and y from listbox (windows phone 7.1)

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I have a listbox showing name of place, building, x and y from a wcf service. How can I trigger a click from there and return the result to a map.

My Xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="Results" Height="450" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>

          <StackPanel Margin="0 0 0 20">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding SearchVal}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding X}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Y}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" />

          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

code behind my click action (Code from other sources)

```
        public void searchResult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //adds the map Point to the map when a results is selected.
        var selectedSearchBtn = (Button)sender;
        var selectedVal = (string)selectedSearchBtn.Content;
        Classes.Global.searchedValue = selectedVal;
        for (int i = 0; i < searchVal.Count; i++)
        {
            if (searchVal[i].Equals(selectedVal))
            {
                Classes.Global.posx = posx[i];
                Classes.Global.posy = posy[i];
            }
        }

        NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
```

How can I use the above code to take the X and Y out ?

Comment: @FunksMaName appreciate if you could help me =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void searchResult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button; //Assuming your trigger is a button UI element.

        if (button != null)
        {
            var place = button.DataContext as TestMap.Classes.Global.Place;

            if (place != null)
            {
                Classes.Global.posx = place.posx;
                Classes.Global.posy = place.posy;
            }
        }

        NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the onclick, I have posted my question for displaying results in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366759/getting-request-onclick-windows-phone Hope if you can help, thanks a lot ! =)